# Wordpress doesn't listen to new .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I was messing around with the .htaccess file, and suddenly after some uploads, wordpress stopped listening to the new .htaccess file. Somehow it uses my previous one although I've replaced it several times with the deafult one. I've downloaded the one which is on the server, and it shows me that it's the deafult one, but when I upload it back again, it doesn't do much.

I also deleted the rewrite_rules record from wp_options table, but still it keeps using an outdated Rewrite Rule..

Does WP save it in it's database somewhere else ? I'm really clueless, thanks for your help !

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache or use new browser and window.

Comment: You're my hero, thanks !